# Auto-Populate or Pull list row data from one page into another on clicking Link button ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, pagination, auto-populate

I have created a list with Link(react-router-dom) against each row called Edit. When I click on Edit I am required to navigate into another page and then auto-populate row value like clientName into that page. Any hint as to how this can be achieved in ReactJS.

Thanks in advance
Anup.P

Comment: would be good to share some code so it'll be easier to help you.

Comment: Actually I am trying to figure out the logic behind the operation. Here I have a list filled with JSON'd values. beside to the every row in list I have put a create button. Now on clicking the button I will open another page wherein I want to auto-fill all the particular row values into the opened page. I use ReactJS -v@16.10. I wish I can share screenshots here. My thinking is I need to setState with row value and then pass it as props and use it in the opened window. Any suggestion will be helpful.